why the integral is from -T/2 to T/2 in the formula of determining signal power?
Can someone explain why they use the interval -T/2 to T/2 rather than simply 0 to T in the formula of determining signal power? they don't even bother to explain it. The screenshot is from the book "Linear systems and signals Book by B. P Lathi" chapter 1.


Suppose the signal is u(-t) and then try the formula where you only integrate over positive time and you'll see what the problem is.

Note that the formula takes the limit of this integral for \$T\$ going to infinity. If the integral was taken over \$[0, T]\$, the overall limit would only account for the signal's power for positive \$t\$, missing the entire range \$t=[-\infty, 0]\$. That would of course lead to wrong results for any signal that has non-zero amplitude at any \$t < 0\$.
